# How to enable Script Documents for Visual studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I want to debugging my javascripts in Visual studio. But after running web site I can't find "Script Documents" node in my Solution explorer. I tried to find some option which turns off/on this node but the result was unsuccessful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I actually came across this issue today. I was not aware of this feature, and had been debugging my web applications using FireFox by default. Using a browser other than 'Internet Explorer' prevents the 'Script Documents' node from working.

Are you using Internet Explorer to debug, or more specifically, when you debug in Visual Studio, is Internet Explorer being launched? If another browser is launched, and you launch Internet Explorer manually and navigate your site, 'Script Documents' will not appear.

I am currently looking to see if there is anyway to hook this feature into another browser, but here is something you can look at if indeed this is the problem.

1. Right-click on any .aspx file in your project
2. Click on 'Browse With...'
3. You should see a dialog appear, which may already list all installed browsers.
4. Select Internet Explorer, and press 'Set as Default'

While debugging, you should now see the 'Script Documents' node.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things, but I only got it working again after I changed the default browser to Chrome and then switched it back to Internet Explorer.